# Angularjs populate control conditionally

Tags: html, angularjs

I have json data like this

```
data= [ ...
    .........
    .........
    contact:[
    { 
      type: 1,
      Name: xxxx,
      city: XX city
    },
    { 
      type: 2,
      Name: yyyyy,
      city: YY city
    },
    { 
      type: 3,
      Name: zzzz,
      city: ZZ city
    }]
  ]
```

Now I have html like this:

```
<div id='type1'>
    Some other info for type 1
    <div>{{data.contact.Name}}</div>
    <div>{{data.contact.city}}<div>
</div>
<div id='type2'>
    <dl>
         <dd>{{data.contact.Name}}</dd>
         <dt>{{data.contact.city}}</dt>
    </dl>
    Labels are different for type 2
</div>
<div id='type3'>
  Entire color, label and controls are different for type 3
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>{{data.contact.Name}}</td>
         <td>{{data.contact.city}}</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Type1 div should be bind with contact of type 1 only, same for type 2 and 3 .

List of controls are big in every section any ternary kind of logic should be avoided.

A simple for loop cannot work here.

Comment: there isn't enough markup here or an expected result to explain what your statements actually mean.  You are likely to receive answers with loop logic, simply because you haven't explained ***why*** a loop wouldn't work, or shown data to the contrary.  As an aside, you really didn't ask a question, merely posted some code you appear to be having trouble with and said "This is what I want".

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `ng-repeat` directive for such case, you need not to worry about the rendering, JSON will be repeated the div for as many number of types are there.

**Markup**

```
<div id="{{c.type}}" ng-repeat="c in data.contact">
   {{c.Name}}: {{c.city}}
</div>
```